# How to popup QCompleter on entering cell editing in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qcompleter, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a `QTableWidget` with custom `QStyledItemDelegate` and when enter in cell editing, I want to popup a completer but it doesn't appear.

The setup of delegate:

```
tableWidget.setItemDelegate(new DelegateLineEdit());
```

My custom class:

```
class DelegateLineEdit : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    DelegateLineEdit() {
        signs << "<" << "<=" << ">" << ">=" << "=";
    }
    ~DelegateLineEdit(){ }
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
        QLineEdit *line_edit = new QLineEdit(parent);
        line_edit->setStyle(parent->style());
        line_edit->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
        QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(signs, line_edit);
        completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
        line_edit->setCompleter(completer);
        return line_edit;
    }
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const {
        QStyledItemDelegate::setEditorData(editor, index);
        QLineEdit *line_edit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
        if (line_edit){
            line_edit->completer()->complete();
        }
    }

private:
    QStringList signs;

};
```

When I enter in cell editing by double click, nothing happen but if I comment the line
`line_edit->completer()->complete()`, I can edit the cell but no completion is show. Somebody have an idea ?

Comment: I would get rid of the `setEditorData` altogether. The completer should pop up when the user starts typing, no extra actions needed in code.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o, Yes when you start typing it's pop up, but I would like to pop up when the user enter editing even if he hasn't start typing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using a `QLineEdit` subclass as editor, where the `focusInEvent` is overridden to show the popup:

```
class LineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
public:
  explicit LineEdit(QWidget*parent) : QLineEdit(parent){}
protected:
  void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent * e)
  {
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
    completer()->complete();
  }
};
```

The delegate becomes:

```
class DelegateLineEdit : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    DelegateLineEdit() {
        signs << "<" << "<=" << ">" << ">=" << "=";
    }
    ~DelegateLineEdit(){ }
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {

//use the subclass instead of QLineEdit:
        LineEdit *line_edit = new LineEdit(parent);

        line_edit->setStyle(parent->style());
        line_edit->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
        QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(signs, line_edit);
        completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
        line_edit->setCompleter(completer);
        return line_edit;
    }

private:
    QStringList signs;

};
```

Comment: It's work like a charm, I had overloaded the mouseReleaseEvent but focusIn was sufficient, Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I think something like `completer->popup()->show();` should do what you want or try to call like

```
QCompleter::setCompletionPrefix(index.data(Qt::EditRole).tostring());
```

and

```
QCompleter::complete();
```